# Play & Mix Background Audio with Video Camera Recording

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm currently in the process of debugging my video camera model that I'm using to record video and audio. I would like the video camera to continue playing background audio if there is something play and record using the mic over the audio. I initially got my av capture session to work smoothly as intended by adding the microphone input on set up which automatically stops playing background audio when the camera view is set up.

I have been working on the following solution where I add the audio input only when I start recording and attempt to remove audio input once I stop recording. Here is my current code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

// MARK: Camera View Model
class CameraViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject,AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    // MARK: Video Recorder Properties
    @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
    @Published var recordedURLs: [URL] = []
    @Published var previewURL: URL?
    @Published var showPreview: Bool = false

    // Set up is called after necessary permissions are acquired
    func setUp(){
        
        do{
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
          
            let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
            
          if cameraDevice != nil {
            
            /* old code that added audio input on open that worked as intended
              let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice!)
              let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
              let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
              if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) && self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){ //MARK: Audio Input
                  self.session.addInput(videoInput)
                  self.session.addInput(audioInput)
                  self.videoDeviceInput = videoInput
              } */
              
              // new code that only adds video input
              if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                  self.session.addInput(videoInput)
                  self.videoDeviceInput = videoInput
              }
              
              
              if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                  self.session.addOutput(self.output)
              }
              if self.session.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput){
                  self.session.addOutput(self.photoOutput)
              }
              //for audio mixing, make sure this is default set to true
              self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = true
              self.session.commitConfiguration()
          }

        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

   //start recording is called upon a user input which now attaches the mic input
   func startRecording() {
        // here is how I'm mixing the background audio and adding the microphone input when the camera starts recording 
        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.videoRecording)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
            if self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
                self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Can't Set Audio Session Category: \(error)")
        }
         
        
        // MARK: Temporary URL for recording Video
        let tempURL = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "\(Date()).mov"
        //Need to correct image orientation before moving further
        if let videoOutputConnection = output.connection(with: .video) {

            //For frontCamera settings to capture mirror image
          if self.videoDeviceInput.device.position == .front {

              videoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
              videoOutputConnection.isVideoMirrored = true
            } else {
              videoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = true
            }
            
        }
        output.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempURL), recordingDelegate: self)
        isRecording = true
    }

    //stop recording removes the audio input
    func stopRecording(){
        output.stopRecording()
        isRecording = false
        self.flashOn = false
        
        // stop recording is where I believe I'm doing something wrong when I remove the audio input
        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
            self.session.removeInput(audioInput)
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        } catch {
            print("Error occurred while removing audio device input: \(error)")
        }
         
    }
 }
```

I also added the following necessary lines in my AppDelegate launch method as well

```
/*
below is for mixing audio
*/
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
} catch {
    print("Failed to set audio session category.")
}
```

I believe I'm going on the correct track as the first time the app opens, background audio plays smoothly and there is a small camera flash but once I start recording, it mixes the background audio well with the phone audio input as well. I was able to see this in the preview in a new view. However, once I dismiss the preview of the recorded url and go back to the camera, the phone audio mic input stops working completely.

I also receive this error in my console:
AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:1271  Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

When I looked online, it said to stop or pause AVPlayer but I'm unsure where I'm even using an AVPlayer session here. I also noticed that people suggested creating two capture sessions for the audio and video but I was struggling to get that working as well, so went ahead with this option.

Editing for minimal reproducible example:

Here is the camera view model and I've attached the necessary views in a separate answer:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

// MARK: Camera View Model
class CameraViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject,AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    // MARK: Video Recorder Properties
    @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
    @Published var recordedURLs: [URL] = []
    @Published var previewURL: URL?
    @Published var showPreview: Bool = false
    
    // Top Progress Bar
    @Published var recordedDuration: CGFloat = 0
    // Maximum 15 seconds
    @Published var maxDuration: CGFloat = 15
    
    //for photo
    // since were going to read pic data....
    @Published var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    @Published var isTaken = false
    @Published var picData = Data(count: 0)
    @Published var thumbnailData = Data(count: 0)

    @Published var flashOn = false
  
    @objc dynamic var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
    // MARK: Device Configuration Properties
    private let videoDeviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInTrueDepthCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
  
    @AppStorage("camerapermission") var camerapermission = 0

    func checkPermission(){
        
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
          self.checkAudioPermission()
            return
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                
                if status{
                  self.checkAudioPermission()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.camerapermission = 2
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        default:
            return
        }
    }
  
    func checkAudioPermission() {
      switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
        case .granted :
            print("permission granted")
            self.camerapermission = 1
            setUp()
        case .denied:
            print("permission denied")
            self.camerapermission = 2
            self.alert.toggle()
        case .undetermined:
            print("request permission here")
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ granted in
              if granted {
                print("permission granted here")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.camerapermission = 1
                }
                self.setUp()
              }
            })
      default:
          print("unknown")
        

      }
      
    }
    
    func setUp(){
        
        do{
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
          
            let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
            
          if cameraDevice != nil {
            
            
              let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice!)
//              let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
//              let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
//              if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) && self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){ //MARK: Audio Input
//                  self.session.addInput(videoInput)
//                  self.session.addInput(audioInput)
//                  self.videoDeviceInput = videoInput
//              }
//
              /* mixing code buggy  */
              if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                  self.session.addInput(videoInput)
                  self.videoDeviceInput = videoInput
              }
              
              
              if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                  self.session.addOutput(self.output)
              }
              if self.session.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput){
                  self.session.addOutput(self.photoOutput)
              }
              //for audio mixing, make sure this is default set to true
              self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = true
              self.session.commitConfiguration()
          }

        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    public func set(zoom: CGFloat){
        let factor = zoom < 1 ? 1 : zoom
        let device = self.videoDeviceInput.device
        
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            device.videoZoomFactor = factor
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    
    func changeCamera() {
      sessionQueue.async {
          if self.videoDeviceInput != nil {
            let currentVideoDevice = self.videoDeviceInput.device
            let currentPosition = currentVideoDevice.position
            
            let preferredPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position
            let preferredDeviceType: AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType
            
            switch currentPosition {
            case .unspecified, .front:
                preferredPosition = .back
                preferredDeviceType = .builtInWideAngleCamera
                
            case .back:
                preferredPosition = .front
                preferredDeviceType = .builtInWideAngleCamera
                
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown capture position. Defaulting to back, dual-camera.")
                preferredPosition = .back
                preferredDeviceType = .builtInWideAngleCamera
            }
            let devices = self.videoDeviceDiscoverySession.devices
            var newVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = nil
            
            // First, seek a device with both the preferred position and device type. Otherwise, seek a device with only the preferred position.
            if let device = devices.first(where: { $0.position == preferredPosition && $0.deviceType == preferredDeviceType }) {
                newVideoDevice = device
            } else if let device = devices.first(where: { $0.position == preferredPosition }) {
                newVideoDevice = device
            }
            if let videoDevice = newVideoDevice {
                do {
                  let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
                  self.session.beginConfiguration()
                  
                  // Remove the existing device input first, because AVCaptureSession doesn't support
                  // simultaneous use of the rear and front cameras.
                  self.session.removeInput(self.videoDeviceInput)
                  
                  // MARK: Audio Input
                  
                  if self.session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput){
                      self.session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                    self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput
                    
                  }

                  if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                      self.session.addOutput(self.output)
                  }
                  if self.session.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput){
                      self.session.addOutput(self.photoOutput)
                  }
                  self.session.commitConfiguration()
                } catch {
                  print("Error occurred while creating video device input: \(error)")
                }
            }

          }
      }

    }
 
    
  // take and retake functions...
  func switchFlash() {
    self.flashOn.toggle()
  }
    
    func takePic(){
      let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
      if flashOn {
        settings.flashMode = .on

      } else {
        settings.flashMode = .off

      }
      //Need to correct image orientation before moving further
      if let photoOutputConnection = photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
          //For frontCamera settings to capture mirror image
        if self.videoDeviceInput.device.position == .front {
              photoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
              photoOutputConnection.isVideoMirrored = true
          } else {
              photoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = true
          }
          
      }
      
      self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
      print("retaking a photo taken...")

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            //self.session.stopRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
            }
        }
    }
  
    func reTake(){

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            self.session.startRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
                //clearing ...
                self.flashOn = false

                self.picData = Data(count: 0)
            }
        }
    }
  
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        
        print("pic taken...")
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
        
        self.picData = imageData
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        /* mixing code buggy */
        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.videoRecording)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
            if self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
                self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Can't Set Audio Session Category: \(error)")
        }
         
        
        // MARK: Temporary URL for recording Video
        let tempURL = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "\(Date()).mov"
        //Need to correct image orientation before moving further
        if let videoOutputConnection = output.connection(with: .video) {

            //For frontCamera settings to capture mirror image
          if self.videoDeviceInput.device.position == .front {

              videoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
              videoOutputConnection.isVideoMirrored = true
            } else {
              videoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = true
            }
            
        }
        output.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempURL), recordingDelegate: self)
        isRecording = true
    }
    
    func stopRecording(){
        output.stopRecording()
        isRecording = false
        self.flashOn = false
        
        /* mixing code buggy */

        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
            self.session.removeInput(audioInput)
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        } catch {
            print("Error occurred while removing audio device input: \(error)")
        }
         
    }
  
  func generateThumbnail() {
    let image = self.imageFromVideo(url: previewURL!, at: 0)

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.thumbnailData = image?.pngData() ?? Data(count: 0)
       }
  }
    
  func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval) -> UIImage? {
      let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

      let assetIG = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
      assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGenerator.ApertureMode.encodedPixels

      let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 60)
      let thumbnailImageRef: CGImage
      do {
          thumbnailImageRef = try assetIG.copyCGImage(at: cmTime, actualTime: nil)
        print("SUCESS: THUMBNAIL")
      } catch let error {
          print("Error: \(error)")
          return nil
      }

      return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImageRef)
  }
  
    func restartSession() {
      if !self.session.isRunning {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
          self.session.startRunning()
        }
      }
      
    }
    
    func stopSession() {
     // DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
          self.session.stopRunning()
     // }
    }
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        // CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
        print(outputFileURL)
      guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: outputFileURL) else {
          return
      }

      print("File size before compression: \(Double(data.count / 1048576)) mb")
        self.recordedURLs.append(outputFileURL)
        if self.recordedURLs.count == 1{
          
            self.previewURL = outputFileURL
          
            self.generateThumbnail()
            return
        }
        
        
        /*
         Below code can be ignored because only recording one url
         */
        
        
        // CONVERTING URLs TO ASSETS
        let assets = recordedURLs.compactMap { url -> AVURLAsset in
            return AVURLAsset(url: url)
        }
        
        self.previewURL = nil
        // MERGING VIDEOS
        mergeVideos(assets: assets) { exporter in
            exporter.exportAsynchronously {
                if exporter.status == .failed{
                    // HANDLE ERROR
                    print(exporter.error!)
                }
                else{
                    if let finalURL = exporter.outputURL{
                        print(finalURL)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.previewURL = finalURL
                          print("inside final url")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func mergeVideos(assets: [AVURLAsset],completion: @escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession)->()){
        
        let compostion = AVMutableComposition()
        var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
        
        guard let videoTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
        guard let audioTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
        
        for asset in assets {
            // Linking Audio and Video
            do{
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: lastTime)
                // Safe Check if Video has Audio
                if !asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).isEmpty{
                    try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
                }
            }
            catch{
                // HANDLE ERROR
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            // Updating Last Time
            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, asset.duration)
        }
        
        // MARK: Temp Output URL
        let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "Reel-\(Date()).mp4")
        
        // VIDEO IS ROTATED
        // BRINGING BACK TO ORIGNINAL TRANSFORM
        
        let layerInstructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        
        // MARK: Transform
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.rotated(by: 90 * (.pi / 180))
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
        layerInstructions.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)

        let instructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instructions.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: lastTime)
        instructions.layerInstructions = [layerInstructions]

        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.width)
        videoComposition.instructions = [instructions]
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: compostion, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else{return}
        exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
        exporter.outputURL = tempURL
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
        completion(exporter)
    }



  func compressVideo(inputURL: URL,
                     outputURL: URL,
                     handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void) {
      let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
      guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset,
                                                     presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
          handler(nil)

          return
      }

      exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
      exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
      exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
          handler(exportSession)
      }
  }
}
```

You can ignore the merge videos code as there is only one recorded url but right now, you should be able to run this code if you've added camera and microphone permissions to your info.plist.

It currently has the buggy mixing code where background audio does work the first time but after restarting audio session, it no longer works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably entirely manage the audio session yourself, instead of letting `AVCaptureSession` do some of it.

Comment: Can you please share minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I've attached a minimum reproducible example as an edit to my question and answered with the views required to work with the view model. Any assistance towards either making this code work or using av capture session with a separate audio session would be greatly helpful!